# Checking proof for: It is possible to find addition assumptions on the sets $A$ and $B$, so $P(A)\cup P(B) = P(A\cup B)$.

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

It is possible to find additional assumptions on the sets $A$ and $B$ so that in fact
$P(A)\cup P(B) = P(A\cup B)$.

Prove that for all sets $A$ and $B$, if $A=B$ then $P(A)\cup P(B) = P(A\cup B)$.

Solution: Suppose $A=B \implies P(A) = P(B) \implies P(A) \cup P(B) = P(A)$ and $P(A \cup B) = P(A \cup A) = P(A)$.

Thus, $P(A) \cup P(B) = P(A) = P(B) = P(A \cup B)$

By containment (or inclusion), let $X \in P(A \cup B) \implies X \subseteq (A \cup B).$

$\implies X \subseteq (A \cup A) = (B \cup B) \implies X \subseteq A=B$.

$\implies X \in P(A) = P(B) \implies X \in P(A) \cup P(B)$.

$\implies P(A \cup B) \subseteq P(A) \cup P(B)$.

As $P(A \cup B) \supseteq P(A) \cup P(B)$. Thus, $P(A) \cup P(B) = P(A \cup B)$.

Comment: Does $P$ represent the power set?

Comment: Yes @DonThousand

Comment: While your work is correct, you can find a slightly looser condition (i.e., $B\subseteq A$ or $A\subseteq B$). With this condition, try proving the claim in both directions.

Comment: Is it still true if $A \cap B = \phi $ that $P(A \cup B)=P(A) \cup P(B)$?

Comment: Yes because it is possible that the power sets can only share the empty set right? @FareedAF

Comment: Good way to figure out these elementary set problems is to just draw a few dots for each set on a sheet of paper. Usually everything becomes obvious then.

Comment: @Klaus Thank you. Is there any way anyone can help me with the other problem I just posted? I am clueless as to how to solve it. I just posted it a minute ago.